# Filter dataframe by values already occurring in another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This shouldnt be a hard problem, however I'm not sure why all the methods I've tried don't seem to work.

Basically I have 2 dataframes of ports, the larger one is around 3600 ports, while the other has roughly 660. The smaller dataframe is just a returned dataframe from a query from my database to see which ones in the larger dataset I already have to avoid redundant entities.

So in this case it's just a simple filter to see if the name occurs in both dataframes drop it from the large one. I've referenced several other questions and tried the fixes and I'm not sure why they aren't working.

```
Data frame 1 

            X          Y   FID  INDEX_NO  REGION_NO        PORT_NAME COUNTRY  \
0 -124.066667  44.800000  1001     16835      16000        DEPOE BAY      US   
1 -124.050000  46.300000  1002     16838      16000           ILWACO      US   
2 -122.483333  37.500000  1003     16290      16000       PRINCETOWN      US   
3 -105.266667  20.616667  1004     15790      15700  PUERTO VALLARTA      MX   
4 -106.416667  23.200000  1005     15810      15700         MAZATLAN      MX   

Dataframe 2

      eid                 name  
0   AAAA       Port of Manta   
1   BBBB       port of Antofagasta   
2   CCCC       port of IJmuiden   
3   DDDD       port of Augusta   
4   EEEE       port of Grimsby
```

I did some basic string cleaning to avoid any mishaps, so lowercasing the names of both port features.

I've tried two methods of filtering and they only take out roughly 77 of the 660 ports from DF1. I figured it was initially poor case of matching, but checking the names in excel to see if they occur in both shows all 660 occuring in both dataframes.

```
# Method 1

world_ports['PORT_NAME'] = world_ports['PORT_NAME'].str.lower()

match_df = world_ports[~world_ports['PORT_NAME'].isin(port)]



# Method 2
count = 0

for a, b in existing_ports.iterrows():

    count += 1
    percentage = round(100 * (count / len(world_ports.PORT_NAME)), 2)
    print('\rPercent Completed: ', percentage, '%', 'Search Term: ', b['name'], end='', flush=True)

    n_name = b['name'].lower().replace('port', '').replace('of', '').strip() # tried this filter option
    n_name = b['name'].lower() # tried this filter option

    for c, d in world_ports.iterrows():

        e_name = d['PORT_NAME'].lower().strip()

        if n_name in e_name is True:
            print('Matches: ', n_name, ': ', e_name)
            world_ports = [~world_ports.PORT_NAME.isin(n_name)]

print(len(world_ports))
```

I've tried `isin()`,`contains()` but none of them work properly.

I also checked to see if some ports contain odd characters like `Cẩm Phả Port` vs `Cam Pha Port` but I don't know how to replace all occurrences of those letters with generic letters without deleting the whole string.